# ruby rails - save method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, soap, savon

I created a data model, I am using mysql database. I use savon for handling SOAP requests. On the console I can see SOAP controller debug creating data.  Most of the part of part of is working, expect saving the created information.

How do I bring in the `save` method? I want to save the successfully received response from a soap request. The actual code is big, so trying skip posting it here. I will post if required.

```
rails g model ticket ticket_num:string t_status:string priority:string solution:string  misc:string
rails generate controller ticket create
rake db:migrate
```

#### Controller Code:

```
class TicketController < ApplicationController
  def create
    ticket = Ticket.createticket(params[:caller], current_user.user_id, current_user.firstname, current_user.lastname, current_user.email)
    ticket.save
  end
end
```

#### Error Message:

```
NoMethodError in TicketController#create

undefined method `save' for #<Savon::SOAP::Response:0xaed6da4>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the code, but I'm guessing the problem is that you're not returning your newly created `Ticket` object at the end of your `Ticket.createticket` method. You're probably doing something with your Savon client on the last line of the method so it's returning that instead of the new `Ticket` object.

Comment: Thanks. That's what it was, I was returning stuff that wasn't exactly the data object.